# Regex | steals character class from another element in a group

Tags: regex

**The task:**
I need to find all abbreviations of address object identifiers in a string using a list of said abbreviations. (To delete them later).
(Abbreviations list is in another language and is waaaay bigger (200+ elements), so foreach is out of question due to "complex regex beats foreach in speed").

**The problem:**
Regex like this `(?:[^\w\d]|\A)(?:street|str|c|city|state|st|apt)([^\w\d]|\Z)`
works on a string like this: `Klutc state, Beast st, apt c5`
and correcttly gives `state, st, apt`.

But on a string: `state Klutc, Beast st,apt c5` it returns `state` and `st`, but not `apt`, because the `[^\w\d]` is somewhat stolen by the previous `st`

I also cannot use just the `(?:[^\w\d]|\A)(?:street|str|c|city|state|st|apt)` (left side) because it will not work on `Klutc state, Beast st, apt c5` and give `c` from `c5`

Neither can I use only the right side `(?:street|str|c|city|state|st|apt)([^\w\d]|\Z)` because on a string `Klutc state, Beast st, apt c5` it will return `st` from `beast` and `c` from `Klutc`.

**The question:**
How should I rewrite the regex, so it correctly return the abbreviations only? (Make `st,` not steal `,` from `,apt`, i.e. make `st` and `apt` both use the same `,`). Test inputs are:

```
Klutc state, Beast st, apt c5

state Klutc, Beast st,apt c5

Klutc State,Beast st,c5 apt
```

Comment: it's not apparent in your question how this relates to `c#`.  are you expecting the answer to be using `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace, `Regex` type.. do you have any code as it relates to this in c#?

Comment: Instead of non-capturing group, (?:[^\w\d]|\A) use positive lookbehind at the beginning  (?<=[^\w\d]|\A) and positive lookahead at the end (?=[^\w\d]|\Z).  Read up on this very useful feature.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer, Many thanks! How can I mark your comment as an answer?

Comment: You can't, but you can ask them to post it as an answer and then accept it, or post it yourself (perhaps as a "community wiki" where you abstain from reaping any reputation from any upvotes); but probably this is too vague and a duplicate. Please review [the `regex` tag guidance](/tags/regex/info) and update your question to provide the details which have been requested above.